# Probability of selecting the index corresponding to the higher parameter looking at frequencies of independent Bernoulli processes.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, probability-limit-theorems

Let $0\le p_1 \le p_2 < \dots \le p_{n-1} < p_n \le 1$.
Let

- $X_1^1,X^2_1,X^3_1,\dots\sim B(1,p_1)$;
- $X^1_2,X^2_2,X^3_2, \dots \sim B(1,p_2)$;
- $\dots$
- $X^1_n,X^2_n,X^3_n, \dots \sim B(1,p_n)$;

be a family of independent random variables, where $B(1,p)$ is a Bernoulli of parameter $p$.

For all $t\in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ define the frequencies corresponding to the $j$-th Bernoulli process as:
$$f^t_j=\frac{1}{t} \sum_{s=1}^t X^s_j.$$

Can we provide a good lower bound depending on $t$ and $n$ (a plus if the lower bound is valid not only asymptotically in $t$) on the probability of the event
$$\{f^t_n \ge \max_{j< n}f^t_j\}?$$

It is clear (since the distributions of the $f^t_j$ approach to the distribution of a Dirac in $p_j$ as $t \to \infty$) that the probability of this event approaches one as $t \to \infty$  but at which rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain a precise bound using Hoeffding's inequality.
By Hoeffding's inequality, $\mathbb{P}(f_n^t \leq p_n-\epsilon)\leq  \exp(-2t\epsilon^2)$. Also,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\max_{j<n} f_j^t \geq p_n-\epsilon) &\leq (n-1)\mathbb{P}(f_{n-1}^t \geq p_n-\epsilon)\\
&=(n-1)\mathbb{P}(f_{n-1}^t \geq p_{n-1}+(p_n-p_{n-1}-\epsilon)) \\ 
&\leq (n-1)\exp(-2t(p_n-p_{n-1}-\epsilon)^2).
\end{align*}
Choose $\epsilon=(p_n-p_{n-1})/2$, to obtain that
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{P}(f_n^t \leq  \max_{j<n}f_j^t) \leq  \mathbb{P}(f_n^t \leq p_n-\epsilon) + \mathbb{P}(f_n^t \geq p_n-\epsilon\text{ and } \max_{j<n} f_j^t \geq p_n-\epsilon) \\
&\leq \exp(-2t\epsilon^2) + (n-1)\exp(-t(p_n-p_{n-1})^2/2) \\
&\leq n\exp(-2t\epsilon^2).
\end{align*}